# How to add application to all programs list above the folders?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, deployment

I am wondering how to add the application shortcut to the all programs list in the start menu, not in a folder but above the folders. Where it displays the application shortcuts, and not the folders. I will be using clickonce to deploy my application, does it have this feature built in?

Also is there a way to automatically add application to favourites menu when you first open the start menu?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the shortcut to the following directory would show the program on programs list above the folders:

```
C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the first post - show video you have all steps

LInk : http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2009/04/07/creating-a-desktop-shortcut-for-a-click-once-application/